# The mapping $ x^*\rightarrow \sum x^*x_n$ is continuous in dual space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space,$X^*$ be its dual space.Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$ s.t. $\sum x^*x_n$ converges whenever $x^*\in X^*$, how to show the mapping: $ x^*\rightarrow \sum x^*x_n$ is bounded

Comment: Closed graph theorem.  Recall $X^*$ is a Banach space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniform boundedness principle UBP (if I have understood the notation correctly). 
Set $S_N=\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}$ and consider the family of continuous linear maps
$T_N: X^* \rightarrow {\mathbb C}$ between Banach spaces given by $T_N(x^*) = \langle x^*, s_N\rangle$. Then the family is point wise bounded (you don't need convergence here), i.e. for each  $x^*\in X^*$ we have
   $$ |T_N (x^*)| \leq M(x^*)<+\infty$$
uniformly in $N$. By the UBP there is $M$ finite so that 
  $|T_N(x^*)| \leq M$ for every $x^*$ in the unit ball of $X^*$.

Your convergence gives the supplementary information (perhaps useful) that $T(x^*) = \lim T_N(x^*)$ defines a bounded linear operator.